# Password reset script error

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have the following script for bulk resetting passwords in AD;

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String Password -Force -AsPlainText
get-content "C:\Users.txt" |
Foreach {
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$_'") {Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $securePwd* }
    else {Write-host "Password reset for $_ failed."}
}
```

From what i've seen online this should work, but i'm getting the following error;

```
Set-ADAccountPassword : Cannot bind parameter 'NewPassword'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString*" value
of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
At C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ResetPasswords.ps1:5 char:80
+     if (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$_'") {Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $ ...
+                                                                                   ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADAccountPassword], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccoun
   tPassword
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Any reason on why you're using the wilcard (*) here: `-NewPassword $securePwd*` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `*` is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the * after where you use the password:

`Import-Module ActiveDirectory $securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString
 -String Password -Force -AsPlainText get-content "C:\Users.txt" | Foreach {if (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$_'") {Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $securePwd } else {Write-host "Password reset for $_ failed."} }`